# How to get posts using category slug in ClassiPress?

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, loop

I'm using the ClassiPress theme as a base for a new theme. If you have worked with classipress, you should know that classipress handles its own category using the taxonomy `ad_cat`.
That said, I have a category named `7star` and the following query to get the posts inside that category:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type'=>'ad_listing','category_name'=> '7star') );
```

Unfortunately this query does not work. It only fetches the posts withing categories that are of type `category` not `ad_cat`.
Anybody got any idea how to solve this?
I'm trying to avoid using manual sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I should have used the `tax_query` parameter. Something like the following:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type'=>'ad_listing',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'ad_cat',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => '7star'
    )
)
) );
```